# Jackson @JsonAlias annotation not working

Tags: java-8, jackson, dropwizard

The requirement is to deserialise "name", "first_name", "full_name" into name field. For this, I have used Jackson's @JsonAlias attribute. The version of Jackson being used is 2.9.5. For some reason, the deserialisation does not seem to be working as expected.

```
public class Profile {
    @JsonAlias ({ "full_name", "first_name" })
    private String name;

    private String xyz;

    private String xyzz;
}
```

When using:

```
return objectMapper.convertValue(response, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Profile.class));
```

The full_name field does not get deserialised into the name field.

Comment: What do you mean by "oes not seem to be working as expected"? Is it throw exception? Could you show your code?

Comment: @MichałZiober could you please look at this, I have been blocked due to this.

Comment: I checked your code with `Jackson` `2.9.9` and it works like expected. Which version do you use?

Comment: Version 2.9.5
Do I need to add an equals and hash methods? @MichałZiober

Comment: Could you upgrade your code to `2.9.9`. `equals` and `hash` methods are not required.